# Can't play mp4 from web-server, plays fine from file://

Tags: google-chrome, video, server, local-files

I've tried this running a few simple servers, beefy.js and static-server, both simple node servers.

My problem is that when I load my video via an http:// in a video element, or via a relative path on the local web-server, it doesn't play. I get no errors.
I've checked the address is correct by providing an incorrect address which gives me an error in the console.

If I give chrome a `file://LOCATION_OF_MP4`, chrome will play the video no problem.

If I go to `http://localhost:9080/relative-location.MP4`, I get a black screen with player controls and a muted sound.

I can't figure out why the local version should be fine, but the server-based can't be found.

I'm creating the video tag via

```
var vid = document.createElement('video');
console.log('src', state.demoVideo.store.src());
vid.setAttribute('src', state.demoVideo.store.src());
document.body.appendChild(vid);
```